# a linear algebra multiple choice problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ belongs to $M_3(\mathbb R)$ which is not a diagonal matrix. Pick out the cases  when $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$:

> a. when $A^2 = A$;
>
> b. when $(A - 3I)^2 = 0$;
>
> c. when $A^2 + I = 0$

(a) is certainly true as eigen values are distinct.
(c) is certainly not true as eigen values are imaginary not real. but i am not sure about (b). can anybody help? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (b) the matrix will not be diagonalizable unless it is precisely $3I$. What can you say about the minimal polynomial?